# Is It Possible To Hide A Google Analytics User ID From Source

Tags: google-analytics

I have a client who has registered a domain name with privacy and wants to build out the site but not expose their Google Analytics ID at this time. It generally looks like

```
_uacct = "UA-xxxxxxx-x";
```

Their fear is that their competition might be able to spot them and even though their registration details are private, they could compare the Google Analytics ID on their [private] pages with the ID in their other sites' pages.

They want to be able to compare traffic and would like to stick with Google BUT they are willing to go to another traffic analytics provider if that ends up being the best course of action.

Is there any way to hide that ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately, there is no way to hide it. Worst case, the competitor can just look at the address of the analytics image loaded on the page.

But what's stopping them from creating a separate email address, registering a separate google analytics account and then just adding their original email as full-access co-administrator?

Comment: +1 for the second option - I track several IDs like this (not for privacy) they were just acquired separately.

Comment: Its not that a second GA account is out of the question, they just wanted to keep all their properties under one account - this one included. Eventually when the time is right for them, they wont care about the exposure.  Right now they care.  The option is probably their only option, then..

Comment: Well, a separate account (with first account having admin access to it) is a lot simpler than going to the other analytics provider all together.